# Strawberry Perl using a separate winlibs distro

Tags: perl, mingw-w64, strawberry-perl

Strawberry Perl is distributed with its own winlibs distribution. E.g., if the perl distribution is placed in c:/strawberry, the winlibs distribution is placed in c:/strawberry/c. May I replace this winlibs distribution with a different, newer winlibs distribution placed in c:/winlibs (for example)? Would changes other than the path be necessary? Thank you!

I tried the following:
d:\prog\strawberry with strawberry perl 5.38.2.2 but with the c folder removed;
d:\prog\mingw64 with winlibs 13.2.0 release 6.
I worked the path accordingly. I get errors when trying to install packages. These errors were not there with the original setup.

Comment: *I get errors ..."* - please share the error message(s) you get.

Comment: If you need to compile packages, they must be compiled by the same compiler as the perl itself, otherwise they won't be compatible.

Comment: @choroba: Yes, indeed. I noticed the c\version-info.txt file mentioning "winlibs personal build version gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5" and "This build was compiled with GCC 13.1.0 and packaged on 2023-06-04." The same winlibs download, i.e. exactly matching this file, is not absolutely identical to the winlibs included here. The difference is certainly relevant.

Comment: @Filburt: with the original setup I tried to install via CPAN PDF::API2. It worked flawlessly. But with the substitution I tried, it failed, with dependency errors.

Comment: Also [asked on /r/perl](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/1bndmdx/strawberry_perl_using_a_separate_winlibs_distro/). When cross-posting, it's polite to let people know that there already be an answer somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Strawberry Perl is a bear of a project: it brings together many components, compiles them together, links all the objects, and gives you a tidy package. If you wanted to replace part of that, all the other parts must be redone too. And, all of that has to done with the same compiler the original package used.

You could compile your own Strawberry Perl, but why? Are you running into some problem that you think a different winlibs would solve?

Have you considered raising an issue with [Strawberry Perl](https://github.com/StrawberryPerl) for the problem you think you have?